# Testing WebOdf Collaborative editor on localServer

Tags: odf, collaborative-editing, webodf

I am trying to add document editor support in my website. I found Opensource WebODF and tried to test it on my local server.  The git repository ReadMe gives instructions on how to add Odf viewer support.
I was able to test the localeditor. Can some one explain how to setup the collaborative editor on local server.

Answer (score 1):

The brief steps are as follows :

1. Download the **Wodo-TextEditor** library from [here](https://github.com/kogmbh/Wodo.TextEditor_release/tree/v0.5.9).(It has the webodf library included as dependency).Put the library in your server or root directry of application,so you can access it from html page.
2. Then include the editor scripts in your html as done in sample html below.
3. Make sure you have a *odt* document on your server or you can use **welcome.odt** sample document included in **Wodo-TextEditor** library.
4. And load the editor as in sample or you can just pick the whole html as it is ,just make sure all your include paths are valid.
5. And that should be it !

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327721/how-to-use-the-webodf-editor-in-localhost-with-node-js/34470711#34470711) answer by me to setup a local **webodf editor** for your web application.

For simply using **webodf editor** you can use [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kogmbh/Wodo.TextEditor_release/master/texteditor.html) html page sample .Make sure you have a odt document on your server directory which can be loaded in the editor.