# how to use the webodf editor in localhost with node.js

Tags: node.js, webodf

I did not find any tutorials to how to run the webodf i read his apis and source code i am getting how to start it  can anybody  share the idea.

```
- WebODF version 0.5.10-8-gf5949f3
-- Found Java: /usr/bin/java (found version "1.7.0.91") 
-- external downloads will be stored/expected in: /home/peoplelink/build/downloads
-- Installed Node.js found: /usr/bin/nodejs - 0.10.25
-- good Node.js found: 0.10.25 (0.10.5 required.)
-- npm found: /usr/bin/npm
-- Android was not found: APK will not be built.
JS file dependencies were updated.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to:
```

i got this but i am not getting to webodf.js file in it i am missed out anything.

Answer (score 2):

I am not not sure what you currently have . But This is how you can configure an application using node.js to serve html files and view/edit odf files.

Lets Start with your Node.js Server

1. First Create an index.js file(name it whatever you want)in our application directory,then initialize node application using *node init*.

   We will have following folder structure : -

   - ./ document-editor
   - ../app (our html code and libraries)
   - ../index.js
   - ../package.json
   - ../And some other auto-generated files.
2. Include all the modules necessary.We are going to use Express,Multer and
    other util libraries.

   ```
   var express = require("express"); 
   var multer = require('multer');  //for file handling
   var util = require('util');
   var app = express();   // init express app
   ```
3. Configure Routes and Html files to be served on user request to you server.

   ```
    app.use(express.static('app')); // use this as resource  directory

    //APP ROUTING URL => FUNCTIONS
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.sendFile(__dirname + "/app/index.html");
    });
    // this means when we get a request on 'myAppContext/' url provide   
      index.html
   ```
4. Start the Server

   ```
    //START THE SERVER 
      app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log("Listening on port 3000");
     });
   ```

Note* : Make sure you have node.js envoirnment installed on your system before you start.

Now Lets Look at how we include webodf to our application.

1. First create a directory in your main folder(we name it 'app'), where all 
   the html,styles and scripts..etc will be stored.

   - /app (our html code and libraries)
   - ../index.html
   - ../script

     - ..wodotexteditor-0.5.9(folder)
     - ..myScript.js
   - ../styles
   - ../images
   - ../And some other files.
2. Create an index.html file and include webodf and/or [Editor](https://github.com/kogmbh/Wodo.TextEditor_release) JavaScript libraries(Contains Webodf included in build... so need to download separately).
3. Create a container element and local script necessary to run webodf editor.Make sure to add a odt file to directory for you test or you can use the one which comes with wodo-editor.

   **You can refer [this](https://github.com/kogmbh/Wodo.TextEditor_release/blob/master/texteditor.html) link for creating a local webodf editor using wodo-text-editor and complete the above to steps(2 & 3).**
4. After we have done the above things,we will go into our root directory and run *'node index'* command.... and that's it folks.

   Just hit localhost:3000/ and you will see a workable webodf editor.

I hope this helps to get started with node.js and webodf. I will soon create and full application with open/edit and save features using webodf and node.js.
Thanks :)